Jenkins Problem with generation and launching stages in parallel
What am I doing wrong?
Sequential launch works, Parallel launch breaks with the error:
....
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected named arguments but got org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@21710cb6

def map = [
        Gosha  : 45,
        Gera : 15,
        Serega  : 33
]
def stages_to_run = {
    map.each { key, value ->      
        stage("phase_${key}") {
            echo "name: 'Name', value: ${key}"
            echo "name: 'Age', value: ${value}"
        }
    }
}
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('loop') {
            steps {
                script {
                    // stages_to_run() it works
                    parallel stages_to_run() // it does not work
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


I guess I lack understanding of groovy

In a scripted pipeline parallel expects a map where keys are the stage names and values are the closures to execute in parallel. So your pipeline can be changed like this:
def map = [
        Gosha  : 45,
        Gera : 15,
        Serega  : 33
]
def stages_to_run = map.collectEntries { key, value ->      
    [
        "phase_${key}",
        {
            echo "name: 'Name', value: ${key}"
            echo "name: 'Age', value: ${value}"
        }
    ]
}
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('loop') {
            steps {
                script {
                    parallel stages_to_run
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


@IgorNazarov good to hear. Could you mark it as accepted then?
