Problem with call functions from groovy in Jenkins pipeline
I would like to move everything regarding the definition into a separate groovy file and load it into the pipeline. I've tried different things.
Function is called but and stages_to_run (generation stages for parallel) not started. 'Hello from function' is printed only)
Well, I don't know groove well enough. But I understand that I am calling stages_to_run or function() incorrectly
file: functions.groovy
def function() {
    println 'Hello from function'
    def map = [
        ...
    ]
    def stages_to_run = map.collectEntries { key, value ->      
        [
            ...
        ]
    }
    stages_to_run
}
return this

file: pipeline.jenkins
def commonfunctions
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {     
        stage('Compare:') {
            steps {
                script {
                    commonfunctions = load 'pipelines/functions.groovy'
                    commonfunctions.function()                     
...


.......................

how do you know it's not working? what error do you have? i don't see other prints in your code.

What your function does is return a map of <String, Closure>. There is nothing in the pipeline that would execute it. Try actually running those closures instead of generating a map of them.
def function() {
    println 'Hello from function'
    def map = [
        ...
    ]
    map.each { key, value ->
        stage(key) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
return this


We already connected by generation
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78328956/jenkins-problem-with-generation-and-launching-stages-in-parallel

I would like to move "def map" and "def stages_to_run" to  functions.groovy and reuse it in pipeline.jenkins. But I do not understand as I launch get generation stages for parallel in pipeline.jenkins from functions.groovy

ChatGPT does a pretty good job translating to English. Just saying.

Yes, ChatGPT can do a lot of things
